# Why do 'return', 'continue' or 'break' not work with the comma operator?

Tags: c++, c, comma-operator

I can write the code `if(1) x++, y++;` instead of `if(1) {x++; y++;}`, but in some cases it does not work (see below). It would be nice if you tell me about this.

```
int x = 5, y = 10;    
if (x == 5) x++, y++;  // It works

if (x == 5) x++, return 0; // It shows an error
```

The same applies to `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) y++, y += 5; // It works

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) y++, break; // Does not work
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between *expressions* and *statements*.

Comment: Also note that using [the comma *expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) the way that you do tend to make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Because that's not how the syntax for the comma operator is defined... and that's about it.

Comment: For the same reason that `int i = break;` does not work.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? Just use braces. It's a lot clearer and simpler to understand.

Answer (score 61):

That's because `return` and `break` are statements, not expressions. As such, you cannot use it in another expression in any way. `if` and the others are similarly also statements.

What you can do however is rewrite your expression (for `return`) so that it's not nested in an expression - not that I recommend writing code like that:

```
return x++, 0;
```

You can't do that for `break` because it doesn't accept an expression.

Comment: A nice illustration: there is no appreciable syntactic difference between `x++ / 7` and `x++, 7` (both `/` and `,` being operators). By the same token, `x++, break` makes as much sense as `x++ / break`: none at all.

Comment: @Amadan Nice illustration! I'm sure going to use it next time I have to explain this :) Thanks

Comment: @Amadan There's a highly significant difference (at least before C++17, not sure about the new rules): the comma operator induces a happens-before relationship (or in old terms, introduces a sequence point), which means that `x++, x++` is defined, while `x++ / x++` is undefined.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: There's also the fact that `,` returns the second operand, but `/` divides things, which I'd say is a slightly more significant difference :D . Syntactically though, the only thing that makes them different is precedence ([simplified here](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#expression), [more realistic here](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/research/dsrg/fog/CxxGrammar.y)).

Comment: BUT dont' do it please

Comment: @Rakete1111 how break is different from return?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi `break` is a single statement. There is no `break(e);` or `break e;` like with `return`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `return` and `break` are not statements; `return;` and `break;` are.

Answer (score 11):

The comma operator is for expressions.

The `return` statement and other pure statements are not expressions.

Comment: And the conclusion?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I answered the "Why?" question, didn't I? What is your point?

Answer (score 3):

The comma operator is a binary operator that takes two values.  In this way it is the same as `+` or `*`.  Whereas `+` adds two values and returns the result, and `*` multiplies two values and returns the result, the comma operator simply ignores the value to the left and returns the value on the right.

`2 + 5`  has value `7`

`2 * 5`  has value `10`

`2 , 5`  has value `5`, simply the operand to the right of the operator.

And so you can't write `2,break` for the same reason that you can't write `2+break`.
Because break is a statement, not a value.

What use is a binary operator that ignores one of its operands?  The comma operator ignores the value of the left operand, but the expression is still evaluated. 
Any side-effects of that expression are still realized. Consider:

```
i = 2;
j = 5;
i++, j++;
```

First the two expressions are evaluated. `i++` returns the value `2`, and then increments `i`. `j++` returns the value `5`, and then increments `j`. Finally the comma operator is applied to these two values:  `2,5`  which ignores the `2` and returns the `5`.

Comment: I don't think it ignores the value on the left, but actually evaluates the expression on the left and returns the expression on the right.

Comment: Yes, it evaluates the expression, ... and then ignores its value.  I've edited to make it clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: Nayem, was this helpful at all?

Comment: @DavidDubois Why is everyone saying `break` is a statement? It is not! `break;` is. (Sorry, I am just being pedantic :)

Comment: L.F., you are correct.   How would you fill in the blank?   'break' is a ____, not a value.